# System property, "java.class.path" does not contain classpath added from ant script

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I added classpath to an ant script. Then, in a java file, I wrote "java.class.path" property to get the classpath. When I run a test suite in Eclipse, the classpath is in the property value. However, when I ran the test suite with ant script in terminal, the classpath is not in the property value. I couldn't find the reason.

Here is the ant script snippet. I added "target/class" and jar files to the classpath.

```
<target name="test">
    <echo message="Running unit tests ..."/>
    <junit printsummary="true"
        showoutput="true"
        haltonfailure="false">
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${result.classes.dir}"/>
            <path refid="jmeter_cp"/>
        </classpath>
        <test name="test.JMeterTestSuite"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

And here is java code snippet. It retrieves "java.class.path" property value.

```
stPaths = new StringTokenizer(
    System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
    System.getProperty("path.separator"));
```

I looked at the "java.class.path" value, but it did not have "target/class" and the jar files...

FYI, I'm using an modified ant from a mutation tool(http://mutation-testing.org/). "java.class.path" value contains only libraries for the tool. The tool might delete the classpath that I added. But I'm not sure, so this is why I'm posting this question here.

Comment: The Ant classpath settings are only in force when Ant is running.  It's not available in the JVM that your code runs in.  This isn't a surprise.

Comment: I see.. Is there any way to add the classpath to the ant script so that "java.class.path" property has the classpath?

Comment: Yes, set the classpath when you start your JVM using the -classpath option.

Comment: @duffymo Sorry, I don't get it.  Can you give an example?

Comment: This is Java 101: java -classpath foo.jar;bar.jar;baz.jar YourMain

Comment: @duffymo Oh.. I talking about adding classpath to junit task... I'm running test suite.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51598/discussion-between-jung-hyun-and-duffymo)

Comment: No chat for me.  Same comment applies.  Set the classpath for your JUnit test.

Comment: @duffymo Okay. If you see the ant script above, I set the classpath.

Comment: @duffymo What I'm trying to ask is that why "java.class.path" does not have the classpath that I added even though I set the classpath in the ant script.

Comment: And I've already told you that the Ant classpath has nothing to do with the setting for the JVM when you run either an app or JUnit.  Forget about your Ant script.  Get the JARs into the -classpath when you run JUnit and you'll be fine.

Comment: @duffymo Now I got your point. Thank you. But I need to use ant script.. So, that's why I'm asking about any way to do it in Ant script..

Comment: Ant is an XML build tool.  Once it's done executing, that JVM is closed and you run your app or JUnit.  It has nothing to do with running.  Get the CLASSPATH entries from Ant and manually add them to your JUnit.  Eclipse should have a way to add JARs to test classpath.  Or you could run your tests in Ant using the <junit> task.

Comment: @Jung-Hyun you might have any easier time if you were to use http://pitest.org/ instead of major. It supports modern build tools (e.g maven & gradle) and is designed for ease of use.